# Intuitive explanation of Gauss-Newton regression

Tags: econometrics, nonlinear-regression

I read from a textbook that Gauss-Newton regression is also called 'artificial regression'.  Please give me an example, how does it work? And what's the relation with Newton's method? Thank you.

Comment: there is a Gauss-Newton numerical optimisation method and there is such a thing as non-linear regression. There is no Gauss-Newton regression, at least I never heard about it. Could you please provide the context for your citation, it is not clear for example what is artificial?

Comment: @mpiktas I had the same reaction, but Googling turns up lots of hits.  A context would nevertheless be quite helpful.

Comment: @whuber, from what I found, the Gauss-Newton regression is non-linear regression approximation. Instead of model $y=f(x,\beta)+\varepsilon$ model with Taylor expansion of $f$ is fitted: $y=f(x,\beta_0)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \beta}(x,\beta_0)(\beta-\beta_0)+u$. Here is the [link](http://russell.vcharite.univ-mrs.fr/EIE/fchap6.pdf) where this regression is described. Unfortunately (if you do not know French) it is French translation of [this book](http://qed.econ.queensu.ca/dm-book/).

Comment: the link I gave in previous comment answers your question quite nicely, look at the top of page 178 (the number not the actual PDF page). If no-one answers the question, I will attempt to translate.

Comment: @mpiktas Equation 6.06 and the discussion surrounding it are pretty revealing.  (It's interesting that the book is not as freely available in English as it is in French!)